# Div background image & height not working

Tags: html, css

I have a div main that I have wrapped around my content and a sidebar. I have assigned the #main to have a background image and a min-height of 1200px.

In Google Chrome & Firefox, when I inspect the div doesn't have any properties when I inspect the source. Thus the div's background image and height don't work either.

```
<!--Main content layout -->
#main {
clear:both;
position: relative;
min-height: 1200px;
background-image:url(images/white.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;

}

.sidebar1 {
float: right;
width: 20%;
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
 .content {
padding: 10px 0;
width: 76%;
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;

}
```

The site address is: http://www.tibetskyvillage.org/

Would really appreciate someone elses eyes on this. I use this method all the time and for some reason this time it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

The comment `<!--Main content layout -->` is not a valid CSS comment but an HTML comment instead causing a parse error.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something silly. w3 validator didn't tell me what it was either. Took that out and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: The W3C validator did report a parsing error for me pointing me to the last CSS it parsed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See the screenshot, I have found some disturbances in your layout, to fix this or solution to your problem is
Don't give the image as background in CSS, give it as image in html like this

```
<img width="1360" height="675" src="images/bg0.jpg" class="wraper">
<div id="main">Your content</div>
```

Add styles to the image and main as

```
.wraper {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#main{
position: absolute;
min-height: 1200px;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: If you don't find it suitable, please ignore it or add comment

Comment: That image mountain image is a background image attached to the html definition. On your bigger screen I see the issue and will fix it.